# Why is my destructor being called twice and what is the correct way of implementing similar destructors?

Tags: c++, destructor

I have the following code that ends up calling the destructor twice on an object and crashing. What is the best practice way of implementing this design to avoid such issues?

```
class DataStore {

private:
    uint8_t* data;
    int dataLength;

public:
    DataStore(int length){
        data = new uint8_t[length];
        dataLength = length;
    }

    ~DataStore(){
        printf("DataStore Destructor\n");
        delete [] data;
    }
};

class DataStoreHelper {
private:
    DataStore _dataStore;
public:
    DataStoreHelper(DataStore& dataStore) : _dataStore(dataStore){

    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    DataStore dataStore(10);
    DataStoreHelper dataStoreHelper(dataStore);
}
```

With the following output:

```
DataStore Destructor
DataStore Destructor
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
```

I could fix the problem by storing _dataStore as a pointer, but I really want to know is this the best practice method of implementation or is there a better way?

Comment: The default generated copy constructor and assignment operator functions do a shallow copy of your internally managed array. You have to implement these yourself dojng a deep copy of `data`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: More precisely, they copy the pointer itself, not the array, so both point to the same array, and both try to `delete` it independently.

Comment: @ShadowRanger _"More precisely, they copy the pointer itself"_ When I was young that was called a _shallow copy_, exactly what I mentioned. I didn't know that terminology changed about that the last 30 years, sorry.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Nothing you wrote was wrong, nothing to be sorry about. It's not that the terminology changed, it's just it's ambiguous in some contexts. Some languages have a stricter differentiation (e.g. most languages where all objects are on the heap, like Python, where `lst2 = lst1` aliases/pointer copies, `lst2 = lst1[:]` shallow copies, and  `lst2 = copy.deepcopy(lst1)` does a fully recursive copy to arbitrary depth). For C++ programmers, it's generally fully shallow or fully deep (when written correctly), but since the OP is clearly new to C++, I figured I'd be extra specific.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I see now that I don't want a copy of the object and a pointer is what I should be using here. And in the case I do want a copy, I should be doing a deep copy for allocated memory.

Comment: @PeterSmith I suppose you're doing that as an excercise. If not, you don't need to write that code yourself, but can simply use [`std::vector<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)